# Changing UITextView with if statement from IBAction

Tags: ios, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I've been searching a lot but it seems like I just can't figure it out. I'm pretty new to iOS development and I apologize if I am doing things completely wrong.

Here is the situation.

I am trying to switch the content view of my DetailViewController via button that should send you to the next text view or the same view but with different text.

This is my header file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *rowContent;
@property int rowNumber;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * rowName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *rightArrow;

@end
```

My tableViewController redirects me to my DetailViewContoller depending on which cell I've selected. Now in my DetailViewController I have another button that I want to switch to next text instead of me going back to the tableViewController and selecting a different cell.

```
 //DetailViewController
//set the title of the view
self.title = rowName;

//set the UITextView basec on rowNumber
switch (rowNumber) {
    case 0:
        rowContent.text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"txt"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        break;
    case 1:
        rowContent.text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"file1" ofType:@"txt"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        break;
    case 2:
        rowContent.text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"file2" ofType:@"txt"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        break;
    case 3:
        rowContent.text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"file3" ofType:@"txt"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        break;
    default:
        break;


//TableViewController
 -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
//create and instance of our DetailViewController
DetailViewController * DVC = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];
//set the DVC to the destinationViewContoller
DVC = [segue destinationViewController];
//get the indexPath
NSIndexPath * path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

NSString * theList = [rowList objectAtIndex:path.row];
DVC.rowNumber = path.row;
DVC.rowName = theList;


}
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: How do I connect my UIBarbuttonItem  button to show the next cell context, which is text, without going back and selecting it.

Comment: Selecting this     @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *rightArrow; should redirect me to the next cell. So if I am in case 0 and I press the button, it should switch me to case 1... Thanks for the help btw.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing. If you want to switch to the next case, from a button, just write rowNumber ++; in your button method, and then call the method where your switch statement is.

Comment: This doesn't work as well. :|    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightArrow;
rightArrow = rowNumber++;

Comment: @ZeroOne, I didn't say to make the button equal to rowNumber++, that makes no sense at all. In the button's IBAction, have a line that's just rowNumber++; That will increment rowNumber. Then you have to call whatever method you have that switch statement.

Comment: I've added my TableVIewController code. It is a little bit confusing for me too with path.row?!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, it sounds like you're trying to do something similar to what I recently did in an app. That is, you have a table view in a navigation controller that goes to a detail view when you select a cell, and you want to then be able to navigate between different detail views without going back to the table view to select another cell.

I did this using a UIPageViewController. It is a bit complicated to implement but is a nice clean method to use. The way it works is when you tap on a cell, it goes to a view that contains a UIPageViewController which then loads the appropriate 'page' depending on which cell was tapped. The UIPageViewController handles moving back and forth between pages. You provide a model controller that acts as the UIPageViewController's data source. Its role is to return a detail view controller for a given index (page number). To get the UIPageViewController to load the appropriate data for each page, you feed it the same data you are using to populate your table view.

Say you have three cells in your table. You tap the middle one, and it loads the view with the UIPageViewController. When the cell is tapped and you're transitioning to the detail view, you tell it which cell was tapped. The UIPageViewController then uses this info to load the correct detail view. When the user wants to navigate between pages, the UIPageViewController simply loads the data for the next or previous page with the data that corresponds to that cell in the table view.

Note that UIPageViewController doesn't know or care about the table view, it is simply using the same source data (such as an array) that the table view uses to load its data.

Documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/PageViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH4-SW3).